# FTP Server doesn't allow me to upload .htaccess file

Tags: file, .htaccess, ubuntu, file-upload

I am using Amazon EC2 server. Set up a Ubuntu system and ProFTPD Server. Then I create an user to upload files. It works.

But I can't upload .htaccess file. It returns the following error:

```
 Response:  257 "/public_html" is the current directory
Command:    TYPE A
Response:   200 Type set to A
Command:    PORT 192,168,1,2,200,20
Response:   200 PORT command successful
Command:    STOR .htaccess
Response:   550 .htaccess: Permission denied
Error:  Critical error
Status: Disconnected from server
```

I am managing things via webmin and through Terminal via ssh. I tried following steps:

## DenyFilter         *.*/   (Commented this line on the config file of FTP)

Added GLOBAL like this:

ListOptions "-la"

But nothing works.

An interesting thing is, I can upload .htaccess file to other directories except "public_html"..

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue recently and what ultimately did the fix was to simply rename the file for the purpose of uploading (for example .htaccess-new), then rename it back to .htaccess on the live server.

Be sure to save a back up of the original file, and make certain the file permissions match the original (or are set to whatever you might need.)